# Generating map tile for ol.source.xyz?

Tags: qgis, tiles

I'm trying to create an OpenLayers online map, using QGis/PostgreSQL(PostGIS) to collect data sets and style the map, and then deploying it online.

I previously deployed using PostGIS, GeoServer and GeoWebCache, and learned to use SLD to stlye the map in GeoServer.

Due to the cost and hassle of using a dedicated server to run PostGIS, GeoServer and GeoWebCache (all on Linux), I moved to using map tiles.  This way I could deploy the online map to a standard (cheap) hosting provider.

I started to use the QGis QTiles plugin, which is still considered experimental.  It appears to generate each tile based on features that fall within the bounds of the tile.  This causes large labels that spill out of one tile, but don't necessarily appear in the next tile.

To find an example of the problem, go to: http://thenipissingroad.com/map/?EPSG=4326&coords=-79.6413,45.66620&zoom=14

The town name is "Magnetawan", and is only appearing on one tile cut-off.  If you look around the map at different zoom levels, you'll see many other labels doing this.

Are there other ways to generate tiles than this plugin, or configure the plugin to solve this problem?

I recall using GeoWebCache, and there was a setting (I think) for it to take into acocunt features in neighbouring tiles.  There was a greater computational cost to generate the tiles, but I think it worked better.

Comment: Try this https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QMetaTiles/.

Comment: Thanks so much Ralph. I'm a bit honest to be frank, but somehow didn't stumble upon the QMetaTiles plugin.  I've downloaded the latest stable version and am running it now.

Comment: You could use Mapnik. But then you have to somehow convert your SLD style to cartoCSS or Mapnik XML. Not easy.